# Alternative expressions of the Riemann Siegel Z-function

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

In the [Ivić, Aleksandar (2013). The theory of Hardy's Z-function](https://books.google.com/books?id=cP4gAwAAQBAJ&pg=PR6&lpg=PR6&dq=Ivi%C4%87,+Aleksandar+(2013).+The+theory+of+Hardy%27s+Z-function&source=bl&ots=LUoTCXAQhw&sig=KfdSZ3MFhn5GpMLhb8cI-_1kgWs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9nrX1lsbUAhXJGz4KHaLXCkUQ6AEILjAC#v=onepage&q=Ivi%C4%87%2C%20Aleksandar%20(2013).%20The%20theory%20of%20Hardy's%20Z-function&f=false), page 16 the Hardy function is defined as

$$\begin{align}
Z(t) &:= \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)\left(\chi\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right) \right)^{-1/2}\\[2ex]
&= \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)\left(
\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\,\left(1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)\right) \right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\left(\frac{1}{2}+it \right)\right)}\,\pi^{\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)-\frac{1}{2}}
\right)^{-1/2}\\[2ex]
&= \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)\left(
\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{it}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}\right)}\,\pi^{it}
\right)^{-1/2}\\[2ex]
&=\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)\left(
\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{it}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}\right)}
\right)^{-1/2}\; \,\pi^{\frac{-it}{2}}\\[2ex]
&=\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)\color{blue}{
\frac{\Gamma^{1/2} \left( \frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}\right)}{\Gamma^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{it}{2} \right)}}
\;\pi^{\frac{-it}{2}}
\end{align}$$

The Hardy function is the same as the [Riemann-Siegel Z function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_function) as the Wikipedia entry indicates. The definition in the Wikpedia entry is

$$
\begin{align}
Z(t)&=\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)\; e^{i\theta(t)}\\[2ex]
&=\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)\; e^{i\,\left[ \Im\left(\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2} \right) \right)-\frac{t}{2}\ln(\pi) \right]}\\[2ex]
&=\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)\quad \color{blue}{e^{i \;\text{arg}\left(\Gamma(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2})\right)}}\quad \pi^{\frac{-it}{2}}
\end{align}$$

So the question is (provided I haven't messed up the algebra), How do I see that

$$
\frac{\Gamma^{1/2} \left( \frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}\right)}{\Gamma^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{it}{2} \right)}=\;e^{i \;\text{arg}\left(\Gamma(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2})\right)}$$

?

---

I see that the argument of $z = x + i y=\rho\ e^{i\theta}$

$$\theta = \arg(z)= \frac{1}{i}\log\sqrt{\frac{z}{\bar z}}=\frac{\log z - \log \bar z}{2i}$$

so we can modify

$$\frac{\Gamma^{1/2} \left( \frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}\right)}{\Gamma^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{it}{2} \right)}= \sqrt{\frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{it}{2} \right)}}$$

but is $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{it}{2}\right)$ the complex conjugate of $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{it}{2}\right)$?

Comment: Set $\;z:=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{it}{2}\right)\;$ then you want
$\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{z}{\overline{z}}}=\sqrt{\frac{z^2}{z\overline{z}}}=\;e^{\,i \;\text{arg}(z)}\;$ [with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Identities) $\;\displaystyle e^{\,i \;\text{arg}(z)}=\frac z{|z|}\;$...

Comment: It follows from the [duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) @RaymondManzoni

Comment: Forget about the Z-function and look at the functional equation $$\Lambda(s) = \pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s) = \Lambda(1-s)$$
vs 
$$\lambda(s) = (X(s))^{1/2}\zeta(s) = \lambda(1-s)$$

Comment: @Antoni Parellada: if your question is how to obtain the argument of $\;\displaystyle \zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)\;$ then see the ["Quantitative discussion" from this answer up to $(4)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1495533/21783).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Can you consider an answer explaining how $\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{z}{\overline{z}}}=\sqrt{\frac{z^2}{z\overline{z}}}=\;e^{\,i \;\text{arg}(z)}$ follows from the duplication formula?

Comment: @AntoniParellada: The duplication formula was proposed by user1952009 not by me. My point was precisely that no property of $\zeta$ or $\Gamma$ (except $\,\overline{\Gamma(z)}=\Gamma(\overline{z})\,$) was needed for your identity but only complex operations. At the left you have $\;\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{z}{\overline{z}}}=\sqrt{\frac{z\,z}{z\,\overline{z}}}=\frac {\sqrt{z^2}}{\sqrt{z\overline{z}}}=\frac {z}{|z|}\,$ (with $\sqrt{}\,$ the [principal square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number)

Comment: i.e. $\displaystyle\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{|z|}e^{i\arg(z)/2}\,$ using with care the branch excluding the nonpositive reals). The [usual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number) $\;\displaystyle \frac z{|z|}=e^{\,i \;\text{arg}(z)}\;$ allows to conclude. Sorry if this was unclear,

Comment: From whichever definition of $\Gamma$ you use, it should be easy to see that $\Gamma(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ for positive real $x$. So the two entire meromorphic functions $f \colon z \mapsto \Gamma(z)$ and $g \colon z \mapsto \overline{\Gamma(\overline{z})}$ coincide on a set that has an accumulation point in the domain where they are holomorphic. By the identity theorem, $f \equiv g$.

Comment: @DanielFischer OK. So the last sentence of the OP is therefore correct... Thank you. There is more than one unfamiliar concept in your comment, but it helps confirming the intuition behind the transition to the exponential form (unless I misunderstood you).

Comment: @AntoniParellada You can think to the $Z(t)$ function like this : defined for $t$ real as $Z(t) = \zeta(1/2+it) e^{i \theta(t)}$ where $\theta(t)\in \mathbb{R}$ is chosen such that $Z(t)$ is **real** and analytic. It happens that we have a simple expression $\theta(t) = arg\ \Gamma(1/4+it/2) - \log(\pi)/2$ thanks to the functional equation. Thus $\zeta(1/2+it)$ has a zero at every sign change of $Z(t)$, and this is an important point in favor to the Riemann hypothesis